# Java applet will not display

Tags: java, html, applet

I'm trying to run a simple Java applet from a jar file. The jar file runs fine with a typical Frame-based GUI, and the Applet-extension class compiles.

However, when I open my index.html file in a browser (I'm using Safari), there is no applet. In fact, when I select "inspect element" and look at the size of the applet, it is "0 x 0". I assume this means the applet is not recognized/acknowledged at all by the page (although I have little experience with web development).

My directory is laid out as follows:

```
chess/
| index.html
| build/
| | chess.jar
| | classes/
| | | dtadams/
| | | | chess/
| | | | | gui/
| | | | | | ChessApplet.java
```

And here is my index.html file:

```
<html>
<body>
<applet code=dtadams.chess.gui.ChessApplet.class
        archive="build/chess.jar"
        width="600" height="700">
</applet>
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

I've hit a brick wall with this problem -- I'm not sure how to debug pure html in a browser. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my Github if you'd like a closer look

https://github.com/NicoAdams/JChess/tree/gh-pages

Comment: What package do you declare in the ChessApplet class? Should the `code=` be `classes.dtadams.chess.gui.ChessApplet.class`? To allow a fully declared name including its packages.

Comment: Great point, but it still did not work. I'll update the above code though

Comment: what's the contents of `chess.jar` ?

Comment: chess.jar is compiled from the contents of build/classes (as the root class). So the package of the Applet class is dtadams.chess.gui.ChessApplet

Comment: @Elliott Still did not work once I removed the .class. I'm fairly sure it was supposed to be there, the examples at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_applet_basics.htm give a good overview.

Comment: Always [validate the HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) before presuming it is a problem with the applet.  That HTML is definitely malformed.  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.